# How to insert a value starting with "@" in a MySQL table?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to insert a large list of data in a MySQL table. 
Due to performance issues, I'am filling a `List<string>` and with this list I generate my command string to do an unique insert with all my rows.

Here is my code:

```
StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ");

        List<string> aux = new List<string>();

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                aux.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToSTring()));
            }

            cmdText.Append(string.Join(",", aux));
            cmdText.Append(";");
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText.ToString(), conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            };
```

This way, the result of my cmdText, finally is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_Table (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES ('Value1','Value2') ('Value3','Value4') ...;
```

with aproximately 500k rows in teh same insert.

One or more of this rows can contain values starting with '@'

I'm not using parameters ('@parameter'), but when I execute my application,

I get an error like this:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>   "Parameter '@GMAIL.COM' must be defined."

@gmail.com is a value, not a parameter. But it still been interpreted like a @parameter.

**Anyone knows the way to indicate that this is not a param but a value??**

Comment: [Prepared statements.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14376963/4802649)

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build sql querys. **ALWAYS USE PARAMETRIZED QUERYS**

Comment: The obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: if I dont use the concatenation it tooks me 3 hours to insert 500K rows

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Parameterized queries are typically faster than plain ones when used in a loop.

Comment: Then consider using bulk insert or `bcp` utility

Comment: @Tomalak for 500K rows single insert even with parametarized will always be slow unless you go for bulk insert

Comment: where does your data come from? Why can't you just use `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: show me how would you do a parameterized query with a 500k rows table in a foreach loop... I have tried this, opening the connection the foreach statement and doing ExecuteNonQuery inside the loop, and it tooks me 3 hours, with 500 Rows and 30 columns aproxitately

Comment: opening the conection before the foreach statement

Comment: plus of 500K rows

Comment: @e4c5 the data comes from another database with UniVerse DB2 IBM engine

Comment: so dump from that and import to mysql 500k should be doable in a couple of minutes